# Find all exact text between comment in regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i'm not an expert in regex i know enough about regex, but i have tried everything and i got no success.

I have this SQL Comment in procedures:

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                     
Procedure...............: [EDIParam].[STP_TB_Segment_Select_by_SegmentID] 
Funcao..................: Retorna conjunto de linhas de acordo com o tokenID

{TextToFind}

Tabelas utilizadas......: [EDIParam].[TB_Segment]                  
Procedures utilizadas ..: nenhuma                    
Criada por..............: Vinícius Cesar Cestari
Data criacao............: 18/12/2014
Parametros..............: 
                            @SEG_Id INT
SET NOCOUNT ON
Result Set..............: nenhum

Exemplos de uso:   Exec STP_SuaProc         
{TextToFind}                    
Ultimas alteracoes:                    
Data        Nome                  Descricao                     
----------  -------------------  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

----------  -------------------  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

So i have to find `TextToFind` but with this regex: `(?:\/\*\-.*)({TextToFind}).*(?:\-*\*\/)` it only gets the last `TextToFind` and it kinds of ignore the first one, and when i put lazy quantifier he gets the first one but ignores the last. So, i really wanna know how to get all `TextToFind` in the regex Matches.

**OBS:**I'm using C#, and `TextToFind` can only be text.

Comment: You have to specify which parts of the text you want to extract. "I have to find TextToFind" is not clear enough.

Comment: the only capture group must be TextToFind

Comment: Then search with \{TextToFind\}.

Answer (score 0):

With `\{TextToFind\}` you will find all instances of "{TextToFind}".
If you need to get all text between `{TextToFind}`, use `(?<=\{TextToFind\}).*(?=\{TextToFind\})`. And in case you need to get groups of text before the 1st {TextToFind}, between them, and after the last {TextToFind}, use `(/\*.*)\{TextToFind\}(.*)\{TextToFind\}\s*(.*\*/)` that will yield 3 capture groups.

If you need to find any occurrence of `{TextToFind}` inside a `/*...*/` comment, you can use `(?<=/\*.*)\{TextToFind\}(?=.*\*/)`

**NOTE**: you should use `RegexOptions.Singleline` to be able to capture multiline text.

See the C# demo code below:

```
var contents = @"<Multiline text>"; // USE YOUR INPUT HERE
var words = new string[] { "word1", "word2" }; // USE YOUR WORDS HERE
foreach (var word in words)
{
   var pattern = new Regex(string.Format(@"(?<=/\*.*){0}(?=.*\*/)", word), RegexOptions.Singleline);
   MessageBox.Show(String.Join(", ", pattern.Matches(contents).Cast<Match>().ToList().Select(p => p.Value).ToList()));
}
```

Comment: But, TextToFind can be in every placce inside the comment

Comment: Could you please clarify if you need to find any text, or this specific string `{TextToFind}`, or pieces of text in-between the placeholder `{TextToFind}`? I am adding one more option to the answer: returning string `{TextToFind}` within /*...*/ comment.

Comment: TextToFind is an example, it can be any word, that i will pass as a parameter, resuming it is a variable, and it must be a text.